# Java Generic Type new instance

Tags: java, generic-type-parameters

```java
public class PairT <T>{
    public T first;
    public T second;

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(T first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(T second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public PairT(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public PairT() {
    }
```

What is the diffirence between these two `makePair` methods essentially?
Why the second one is grammatically illegal?

First one:

```java
public static <U> PairT<U> makePair(Class<U> cl) throws Exception {
        return new PairT<U>(cl.getConstructor().newInstance(),
                            cl.getConstructor().newInstance());
    }
```

Second:

```
public static <U> PairT<U> makePair(U cl) throws Exception {
        return new PairT<U(
                  cl.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance(), 
                  cl.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance());
    }
```

Comment: first essential difference: first is posted as text (easy to read, copy, ...); second is pasted as image (hard to read, impossible to copy, ...) || [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675) (at least not only as image)

Comment: It's not grammatically illegal. Your grammar is fine. It's the type system that's complaining. U is erased to Object. `cl.getClass()` is `Class<?>`. The result of creating a class with that constructor is an instance of unknown type.

Comment: @user16320675 sorry, I just want to show the error message on the image

Comment: @Michael For the first case, what does param `Class<U>` look like after type erase? It becomes raw type `Class` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Object.getClass()` returns `Class<?>`, so you need to cast. `makePair2` does so directly but at the end, `makePair3` uses `getClass` which isolates where the casting is required.

```java
    public static <U> PairT<U> makePair1(Class<U> cl) throws Exception {
        return new PairT<U>(cl.getConstructor().newInstance(),
                cl.getConstructor().newInstance());
    }

    public static <U> PairT<U> makePair2(U cl) throws Exception {
        return new PairT<U>(
                (U) cl.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance(),
                (U) cl.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance());
    }

    private static <U> Class<U> getClass(U u) {
        return (Class<U>) u.getClass();
    }

    public static <U> PairT<U> makePair3(U cl) throws Exception {
        return new PairT<U>(
                getClass(cl).getConstructor().newInstance(),
                getClass(cl).getConstructor().newInstance());
    }
```